# $_POST not populated

Tags: php, rest, post

I'm having some issues with the PHP REST API of my app.

I'm submitting my parameters in the correct URL format: `baseUrl?param1=val1&param2=val2`

However, the parameters are being filled into the `$_GET` array instead. I've looked into the `$_SERVER` array to see if there is something wrong there, but I can't see anything obvious.

```
$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']="POST"
```

I've also checked my php.ini for `post_max_size` misconfig:

```
post_max_size=32M
```

I'm not able to figure what else could cause the parameters to be placed into `$_GET`

If it helps, I'm using XAMPP on Windows.

Also, using "Advanced REST client" for Chrome, I've noticed that regardless of the method, POST parameters are placed into `$_GET` if the parameters are in the URL, but if I move them into the REST client's Payload field, they show up as POST parameters.

Comment: You can't submit post parameters through the URL. You must do a POST request.

Comment: "*parameters are placed into $_GET if the parameters are in the URL*" -- that's exactly how it's supposed to work.

Comment: @ChipDean The request itself is a POST request. Correct me if I'm wrong, but `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is meant to encode the POST parameters into the URL.

Comment: Actually scratch that, found the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get parameters via `$_POST` which are submitted in query-string. You can get them via `$_GET` array.

`but if I move them into the REST client's Payload field, they show up as POST parameters.`, seeing your trouble, you can always get them with `$_REQUEST`

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing a thought, The place from where you are initiating post request to backend, you have to use post method.

For example if you are using jquery

```
$.ajax ({ type: 'POST' })
```

If angular js

```
$http.post({ 'your code' });
```

Comment: The issue was actually the client's POST method - WebClient.UploadStringAsync() - for some reason, I had to set the header manually for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`